# MVC DefaultConnection connectionstring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a new MVC 4 Intranet Application Project. I was looking for a LocalDb DefaultConnection connectionstring in Web.Config so that I could use enable-migrations and update-database from the Package Manager Console, but there is no connectionstrings section at all.

My understanding was that there should a connectionstring section with a LocalDb connection inserted by default when the project is created.

Is there a way to create one quickly *after* the project is created? I am using VS2012.

Comment: Have you built your solution already and checked the web.config after the build?

Comment: Yes did a full Rebuild Solution

Comment: Would you please post your connectionstring part of your web.config? I can't quiet belive it.

Comment: Just add your own. I don't believe MVC will create this for your automatically.

Comment: @Serv definitely not there. There is not even a connectionstring section. Deal with web.config daily

Comment: You have me baffled. I've just tried both, Mvc4 and the all new template. No connectionstring

Comment: You get one with an internet project, so may add it manually to the intranet template